# updating mysql database using gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, gridview

I'm trying to update my database using `GridView` but I keep getting this error:

```
Parameter '@Param1' must be defined.
```

I'm using MySQL and the `GridView` in Visual Studio.

Comment: I know that you are new to this site but you need to understand how to ask a question. remember the code in question is on your local machine and non of us have access to see what you see which means you need to post the code.. the error is telling you exactly what the error is and how to resolve it, you need to declare `@Param1` what does the stored procedure look like.. please read `FAQ` on how to  `Ask Question`

Comment: I have to agree with @MethodMan. Check the StackOverflow's help first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.